# MySQL 5.7 how to choose root password after mysqld --initialize

Tags: mysql, windows-10

If I do "mysqld --initialize-insecure", it will be fine with login after initialization, but if I omit "insecure", that will be secure initialization, after which I need a password to login, but I haven't set any password yet.

The menu [data-directory-initialization-mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html) indicates that "Regardless of platform, use --initialize for “secure by default” installation (that is, including generation of a random initial root password). In this case, the password is marked as expired and you will need to choose a new one."

I thought that would be the problem, that mysql initializes the super administrative account "root" with a "random password" and "marked as expired", I need to "choose a new one", but how?

Should I try `mysqld --initialize -p 'mypassword'` or should I type some other prompt clause after initialization?

This problem really bothers me(for twice, I gave up last time after a long time  solution searching), indeed I do not need a secure mode to serve data just for testing my app locally, but I'd like to know how to initialize a secure root account for further usages.

I am not sure what I am missing after reading the manu and google it for 4 hours , again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply logged in with the `root` user and the given password which was generated when you use the `--initialize` option. From 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html#data-directory-initialization-server-actions:

> With --initialize but not --initialize-insecure, the server generates a random password, marks it as expired, and writes a message displaying the password:
>
> ```
> [Warning] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost:
> iTag*AfrH5ej
> ```

When you logged in you can change the password with `ALTER USER`. Still from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html#data-directory-initialization-password-assignment:

> 1. Start the server. For instructions, see Section 2.10.2, “Starting the Server”.
> 2. Connect to the server:
>
>    [...]
> 3. After connecting, assign a new root password:
>
>    mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I am looking for. Seems that I really missed a section there. I appreciate your kindness and help.

Comment: master. great answer

Comment: test made on mysql 8.0.20, temporary password is not shown by default when initializing data folder: I have used this command to get this temporary password from the console `mysqld --initialize --console`

Comment: In my case, it was not displayed, not even with `--console`. But I found it in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

Comment: To add on @DerLola 's comment, for Windows I found it located in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server <version number>\data\<computer name>.err

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use mysqladmin.

```
mysqladmin -u root --skip-password password PASSWORD
```